# How to perform update query on deeply nested JSON in mongodb?

Tags: arrays, database, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a nested json data structure in mongodb which looks like:

```json
{
    'tid': 1,
    'matches': [{
        'dord': 1,
        'matches': [{
                'tord': 1,
                'score': 11
            },
            {
                'tord': 2,
                'score': 12
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        'dord': 2,
        'matches': [{
                'tord': 1,
                'score': 21
            },
            {
                'tord': 2,
                'score': 22
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

I want to update the row with `"dord": 1` and `"tord": 1` and change value of `score` from **11** to **100**. How do I do this?

What I already tried:

```
db.collection.update({'tid': 1}, {'matches': {$elemMatch: {'dord': 1}}}, {'matches': { $elemMatch: {'tord': 1}}}, {'score': 100})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/Mi2HnhzkPpE

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/

> The filtered positional operator $[] identifies the array elements that match the arrayFilters conditions for an update operation

```
db.collection.update({ "tid": 1 },
{ $set: { "matches.$[m].matches.$[t].score": 100  } },
{
  arrayFilters: [
    { "m.dord": 1 }, // to match where dord = 1
    { "t.tord": 1, "t.score": 11 } // and where tord = 1 and score = 11
  ]
})
```